# How to drag and drop using cypress

Tags: cypress

I have a slider from 0% to 100% that i want to write an e2e test for. I've test everything I can think of including the below. I get no error messages but nothing happens. The mousemove seem to trigger on the same spot as the mousedown no matter what value a put in the x coordinate. The mouseEvent moves a few pixels when I use right instead fo pageX or pageY but not the actual element.

```
 cy.get('[data-cy="slider"]').trigger('mousedown').trigger('mousemove', { which: 1, pageX: 800, pageY: 569 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have got a `time slider` and the following code works for me. Could you please try the following. Here  We specify `{ which: 1 }` because dragula will ignore a mousedown if it's not a left click ( comments from cypress samples)
Also use `{force:true}` in commands,force events to happen.

```
cy.get('[data-cy="slider"]')
   .trigger('mousedown', { which: 1 }, { force: true })
   .trigger('mousemove', 800, 569, { force: true })
   .trigger('mouseup');
```

Comment: Tried and nothing happens.

Comment: Could you please post the html for that slider.

Comment: `<div data-cy="slider bar" class="x" style="--toThumbPos:50%; --fromThumbPos:10%;">                                                                                        
      <div class="x"><div class="x"></div><!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"}-->
      <div data-cy="from slider" class="x" data-cypress-el="true">
      </div>
      <div data-cy="to slider" class="x">
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>`